# Поиск самого яркого цвета из предложенных в формате "#000000"

Tags: python

```py
def brightest(colors):
    return max(colors, key=lambda c:max(c[1:3], c[3:5], c[5:]))
```

Это решение одной из кат на CodeWars. Задача была найти самый яркий цвет RGB из списка. Конкретно непонятен метод сортировки key

Ниже представлено то, как бы проверялся верхний код и какой результат должен был быть

```py
test.assert_equals(brightest(["#001000", "#000000"]), "#001000")

test.assert_equals(brightest(["#ABCDEF", "#123456"]), "#ABCDEF")

test.assert_equals(brightest(["#00FF00", "#FFFF00"]), "#00FF00")

test.assert_equals(brightest(["#FFFFFF", "#1234FF"]), "#FFFFFF")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `c[1:3], c[3:5], c[5:]` достает из каждого переданного цвета `RGB-hex` значения. Чем больше каждое значение - тем ярче цвет.
2. За счет того, что символы в `python` имеют сравнение, подходящее для цветов (меньше буква/цифра цвета - тусклее цвет), мы можем воспользоваться функцией `max(c[1:3], c[3:5], c[5:])`, которая выберет самый яркий из трех составляющих.
3. `max(colors, key=lambda c:max(c[1:3], c[3:5], c[5:]))` выбирает максимальный элемент из `colors` по заданному ключу, работа которого описана выше.

Comment: А что конкретно в сущности значит "переменная[... : ...]"? В данном же случае при переборке элементов списка, значение 'c' принимает значение стринговое, а я знаком с употреблением квадратных скобок только в обращении к спискам

Comment: @KirillSeleznev в данном случае можно рассматривать строку как список.

Comment: аааа. То есть символы в каждом цвете формируют список из 7 элементов, а сравниваем в первом действии мы : RR( второй и третий элемент)  GG (четвёртый и пятый)  BB ( шестой и седьмой) ?

Comment: @KirillSeleznev да

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Answer (score 4):

В первую очередь, заголовок

> *«Поиск самого яркого цвета ...»*

не соответствует предложенной функции. Эта функция делает что-то другое, именно

- Поиск цвета с наиболее ярким ***компонентом*** в системе RGB

т.е. цвета, в котором один из компонентов (красный, зеленый, синий) более какого-нибудь компонента в остальных цветах (точнее, *не менее*, т.к. может случиться и равенство).

---

Теперь к самой функции `max()`.

Она может заниматься так

- сравниванием **самых элементов** (чтобы определить *набольший из них*),

как и

- сравниванием какой-то **черты** (свойства) этих элементов (чтобы определить элемент *с наибольшей такой чертой*).

(Примерь: Можем сравнивать людей для возраста, для веса, или для высоты, и искать соответственно человека с набольшим возрастом, весом или высотой.)

Когда мы хотим сравнивать для какой-то черты, нужно в параметр `key=` задать функцию, которая каждому (сравниваемую) элементу определит такую черту.

Например

```
max("Маша", "Альбина", key=len)
```

(т.е. сравнивание для количества букв в имени) выдает "Альбина", хотя она в алфавитном упорядочении менее Маши.

---

Но и, наконец, к самому вашему примеру.

```
key=lambda c: max(c[1:3], c[3:5], c[5:])
```

Ламбда-функция присвоит каждому цвету (здесь обозначенному именем `c`) максимальное значение из его компонент (красной, зеленой, синей)...

Значит, сравниваться будут не строки типа `"#RRGGBB"`, а двухзнаковие строки в диапазоне от `"00"` до `"FF"`.

---

*Замечание:*

**Что такое ламбда-функция?**

Когда нам нужна функция (как например в ключевом параметре `key=` функции `max()`,

- но мы будем использовать ее *только один раз*, и
- она *довольно простая*

to вместо

- *долгого определения* перед ее применением, и
- нужности придумать для ее *какое-то имя*:

  ```
  def lightest_component(c):
      return max(c[1:3], c[3:5], c[5:])
  ```
- и - наконец - ее применением:

  ```
  max(colors, key=lightest_component)
  ```

мы можем это сделать в одном шаге:

```
max(colors, key=lambda c:max(c[1:3], c[3:5], c[5:]))
```

**Определение ламбда функции** начинается словом

```
lambda
```

затем следует список параметров

```
lambda    par1, par2, par3
```

затем двоеточие (как признак конца списка параметров)

```
lambda    par1, par2, par3:
```

и наконец выражение — вычисление значения, которое будет функция возвращать:

```
lambda    par1, par2, par3:     par1 + par2 - par3
```

То-же самое в сжатой форме, как оно обычно используется:

```
lambda a,b,c: a+b-c
```

Comment: заголовок я правил, поскольку там было совсем все плохо. Особо не углублялся, просто взял из текста ТСа. Если есть возможность подправьте под задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Всё в принципе просто.
У нас есть цвет #001000, в нём заложена следующая структура #RRGGBB.

На сколько я понимаю идею приложенного кода, то наиболее ярким считается цвет, в котором значение одного из R,G,B цвета выше.

Так же стоит прояснить, что в функции max, как и в фукнции sorted, есть аргумент key, который помогает кастомизировать сортировку под себя. Об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-max/).

При задании аргумента key функцией, каждый аргумент переданный на сортировку передаётся в функцию key, которая должна обработать элемент и выдать некую оценку элемента. После оценки элемента, вступает обычная сущность функции max, найти наибольшее значение.

Так же можно увидеть всё глазами [тут](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html).